# Installing chromeOS theme on ubuntu not working

Tags: gnome, unity, themes, gtk, chromeos

```bash
sudo snap connect [other snap];gtk-3-themes chromeos-themes:gtk-3-themes
error: snap "snap]" is not installed
gtk-3-themes: command not found
```

and when I entered this

```bash
for i in $(snap connections | grep gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes | awk '{print $2}'); do sudo snap connect $i chromeos-themes:gtk-3-themes; done
```

I see nothing

Answer (score 0):

The first one, you need to replace `[other snap]` with the actual name of another snap, such as a GTK application installed via snap in your example. Also, you typo'ed a colon into a semicolon. So it should probably be:

```bash
sudo snap connect leafpad:gtk-3-themes chromeos-themes:gtk-3-themes
```

Also, for the `for` line, I don't think you'll see any output. It just works for a bit then finishes.